# Sending cookies between servers vs sending headers

Tags: node.js, http, express, cookies, http-headers

I'm a bit naive about how to send cookie data between servers. I am aware that in the HTTP request you use Set-Cookie.

Right now, I am sending a header between the servers, for authorization purposes, so that one server is authorized with the other. But I am wondering if there is some advantage to using cookies, if cookies act differently than headers in this case. From what I have read, cookies and headers are one and the same for most purposes?

Using two Node.js servers, one being the web server, the other being the API server, is there any reason why sending a cookie vs a regular non-cookie header is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "cookie" represents shared state between the client and the server.  As was mentioned, the way to set cookie values, is to use the `Set-Cookie` header.  And the way to communicate values that have already been set is to use the `Cookie` header.

Cookies are typically associated with web browsers, as tool to track and identify existing users.  I've never seen cookies used for server to server communication.

The `Authorization` header is good for passing encoded or encrypted strings.

So for example you might see:

`Authorization: "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="`

The value in this case is the base64 encoded string of "username:password"

I wouldn't worry too much about what header you use. You can make up your own `x-my-awesome-auth-header:` Its conventional to prefix a custom header with an "x".

An important thing to consider, is what the header value contains.  If you are communicating over plain `http` make sure you encrypt.

Also consider using open source standards for passing encrypted data such as [JWT](http://jwt.io/)

Edit: To answer your question, is there any reason why sending a cookie is better?  When it comes to server to server communication, its actually much worse to use Cookies, because those servers have to maintain state with other servers.  eg.  When A talks to B, A has to remember what B said when they talk again.  You typically what server to server communication to be stateless, meaning you can throw away data pertaining to authorization and permission after each transaction.  Each transaction has to go through the full authorization and permission resolution process. Its much easier to code, and there is no penalty in terms of security as long as your are protected via encryption

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "cookies" is just jargon for the `Cookie:` HTTP header and corresponding `Set-Cookie:` header. So they are ultimately the same basic thing. Many APIs use the slightly more semantic `Authorization:` header, so that would be a good place to start.